# How Disable image preview blender files on windows 10?

Tags: image, customization, blend-files, windows, installation

I accidentally enabled the tool to provide blender image preview files in Windows 10 but wanted to disable it. **(I've attached a picture of what I'm talking about)**

I've tried uninstalling blender and installing it again but it keeps showing up.

**(I'm using blender 3.0)**

[image]

Comment: This is a function of your operating system not of Blender, however see [these instructions](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18834-enable-disable-thumbnail-previews-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html) for Windows 10.

Comment: On further investigation there was an option to disable the saving of preview images in Blender before version 3.0 under Edit > Preferences > Save & Load > Save Preview Images, but that checkbox seems to have been removed for version 3.0.

Comment: @JohnEason (this print was taken on the desktop) but I didn't want to take all thumbnail previews on the desktop I just wanted to take the blender previews on the desktop

Comment: No idea in that case I'm afraid. The section on Blender file previews is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/previews.html) in the Blender manual but it doesn't really help much. It even mentions that checkbox which appears to have been removed in despite the fact that the manual is for 3.0.

Comment: @JohnEason when I first installed "blender 3.0" the Blend-File previews didn't appear, but I don't know how I activated the tool that allows the system file browser to show these previews as file thumbnails.

had found this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiI_E8m-uFc&ab_channel=NaJaa99) which shows how to disable but it didn't work

Comment: All that seems to do is completely wipe Blender (in this case 2.8) from the machine and then remove any remaining thumbnail files. It won't stop them being created when you save a Blend file.

Comment: and I also found information about what I'm talking about in the blender manual but I didn't find anything useful [here](https://ibb.co/gD84vMd).

Comment: Yes. That video shows the registry entry to that DLL being deleted if you watch carefully but I doubt it helps in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to disable blendfile thumbnails

First let's unregister Blender's DLL that generates thumbnail. For that, we will use a tool integrated in Windows: Regsvr32, which is designed to unregister DLLs.

Open the command prompt and type this command:

```bash
Regsvr32 /u BlendThumb.dll
```

This should popup if successful:

[image: unregister success]

Then, to get rid of the thumbnails that have already been generated, the simplest way is to reset Windows' entire thumbnail cache. Still in the command prompt, write these lines one after the other:

```bash
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
attrib -h thumbcache_*.db
del thumbcache_*.db
```

After that, you can restart Windows and you should not see Blender's files thumbnails anymore while other files' thumbnails will be remade as you go.

If you want to keep the thumbnails off, do not use Blender's installation executable anymore, install new Blender versions only via the compressed zip files.

### How to get the thumbnails back

If you install Blender via its executable MSI file, this process includes the registration already.

Alternatively, you can open Blender, go to `Edit` menu > `Preferences...` > `System` tab > `Operating System Settings` and hit the `Make Default` button:

[image: make default button]

Or, if you like command lines:

```bash
path/to/blender.exe -r
```

And if like me you use [Dotbow's Blender launcher](https://github.com/DotBow/Blender-Launcher), just to <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Register Extension:

[image: blender launcher]

No need to reset the thumbnail cashe, you might need to just refresh your current opened folders with <kbd>F5</kbd> but the new thumbnails will be generated on the go.

Sources:

- [⚓ T84599 Blender thumbnail generation for Explorer is broken in 2.9x](https://developer.blender.org/T84599#1092821)
- [How to Clear and Reset the Thumbnail Cache on Windows 10? | Gear up Windows 11/10](https://gearupwindows.com/how-to-clear-and-reset-the-thumbnail-cache-on-windows-10/#Clear_thumbnail_cache_via_Command_Prompt)